# Wine is using the wrong GPU out of 2 dedicated GPUs installed

Tags: linux, graphics-card, gpu, wine

I have 2 GPUs installed, a 1080ti (which i have 1 display connected to) and a 1660ti without any displays connected.

I am running an application with Wine, and it crashes on startup. There are some errors related to rendering on a surface, but it mentions the 2nd graphics card I have installed (GTX 1660 Ti).

I unbound the 2nd GPU from the nVidia driver and restarted the display manager, and the Wine application works perfectly. So it's all a matter of asking Wine to render using the right GPU. Upon trying to research this I only see questions of people using Wine with an intergrated Intel graphics and a **single** dedicated nVidia graphics card. So the solution to those questions are to use nVidia Optimus which I cannot use in my case.

Is there some sort of environment variable or some solution to force the 1080Ti to be used as the primary GPU for *all* applications?

Comment: Try to select the video card by running something like `DRI_PRIME=1 wine`. You could also try [nvidia-prime-select](https://github.com/wildtruc/nvidia-prime-select).

Comment: DRI_PRIME doesn't seem to work with any number. I don't think I even have prime installed, there's no integrated graphics so I only use discrete GPUs, both of which are nVidia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is not Wine's fault, but DXVKs. DXVK recognised both GPUs, and chose to use the 1660ti. The log after running `WINEDEBUG=+wgl wine <exe>` showed the following

```
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Probing D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  D3D11CoreCreateDevice: Using feature level D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
info:  Device properties:
info:    Device name:     : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
info:    Driver version   : 515.43.4
```

which indicated it was indeed DXVK. After researching about DXVK I came across the following argument which resolved the issue;
`DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME`

The Wine log showed the following info

```
info:  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti:
info:    Driver: 515.43.4
info:    Vulkan: 1.3.205
info:    Memory Heap[0]:
info:      Size: 6144 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]:
info:      Size: 48209 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]:
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x7
info:  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti:
info:    Driver: 515.43.4
info:    Vulkan: 1.3.205
info:    Memory Heap[0]:
info:      Size: 11264 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[7]: Property Flags = 0x1
info:    Memory Heap[1]:
info:      Size: 48209 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x0
info:      Memory Type[0]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[1]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[2]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[3]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[4]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[5]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[6]: Property Flags = 0x0
info:      Memory Type[8]: Property Flags = 0x6
info:      Memory Type[9]: Property Flags = 0xe
info:    Memory Heap[2]:
info:      Size: 246 MiB
info:      Flags: 0x1
info:      Memory Type[10]: Property Flags = 0x7
```

which provided me with the Device Name I need to use in the argument (which was `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti`. The full command was `DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME="NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti" wine <exe>`